# Operands are not assignment compatible

Tags: c, z80

I have the following code:

```
struct something {
  char *(*choices)[2];
};
char* arr[2] = {"foo", "bar"};

int main(void) {
  struct something obj;
  obj.choices = &arr;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this using a normal C compiler (gcc), I get no errors. However, I am compiling for the Z80, and it raises a `ERROR (152) Operands are not assignment compatible`, which is described as:

> An attempt was made to assign a value whose type cannot be promoted to the type of the destination.

I fail to understand how the types of `&arr` and `char *(*choices)[2]` could differ. What can I do to fix this ?

(I'm using the Zilog z80 compiler, which is part of [ZDS 5.2.0](https://www.zilog.com/index.php?option=com_zcm&task=view&soft_id=8&Itemid=74))

Comment: "*normal C compiler (gdb)*" you mean *gcc* here instead of the debugger *gdb*, right?

Comment: It seems you hit a bug. You might want to raise an error with the vendor.

Comment: Does the compiler claim to support ANSI C ?

Comment: That repo isn't the compiler. The compiler came from [Zilog](https://www.zilog.com/index.php?option=com_zcm&task=view&soft_id=19&Itemid=74). You'll have to ask them what version of the C language they support.

Comment: Maybe try using `memcpy`? If only `sizeof(char*(*)[2]) == sizeof(void*)` you could `void *val = &arr; memcpy(&obj.choices, &val, sizeof(void*))`.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the errors alk and and Raymond, I've updated the question. To all those who suggested it was a bug, I'll try to report it to Zilog and I'll edit/add an answer if there's a fix or it turns out it was something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zilog support has claimed that it is in fact not a compiler bug, and that the original code does not compile as it is not strictly ANSI C. It is accepted by GCC because the compiler is "lenient" and has added a few more syntax rules that go beyond ANSI C specification. Here is the full response:

> The GCC compiler, while very good, is not necessarily a perfect
>   implementation of the C Standard. Over the years I have seen a few
>   cases where widely used compilers, like MSVC++ and, less frequently,
>   GCC accept syntax that is not strictly ANSI C when that syntax seems
>   to be a harmless quasi-extension of standard C and there’s no danger
>   of its being interpreted in some alternate, legitimate meaning. This
>   may be another instance of that.
>
> There’s a fine point of C syntax involved and here is my understanding
>   of that point, along with why perhaps GCC allows the customer’s
>   original syntax. Once a function pointer, e.g. a properly defined
>   variable fnPtr, has acquired a definition, it is allowed to invoke it
>   without the preceding * indirection operator through an expression
>   like
>
> `result = fnPtr(x); // This is legal syntax…`
>
> `result = (*fnPtr) (x); // … even though this is “more correct”`
>
> The reason why the 1st syntax shown above is allowed is that the
>   parentheses enclosing parameter x are regarded as a C operator whose
>   type is “pointer to function”. So the presence of those parentheses
>   makes the indirection operator unnecessary when the function pointer
>   is actually used for making a function call. However, in a case like
>   this customer code where you are just using the function pointer in an
>   assignment statement, this doesn’t come into play and so those
>   operands are not, in fact, strictly assignment compatible. However, a
>   user who is not an expert language wrangler can hardly be blamed for
>   expecting that if the function pointer can be used without the * in
>   one place, it should also be acceptable in other contexts. This might
>   be why the GCC developers have apparently decided to accept the user’s
>   syntax.

Here is an alternate version that compiles:

```
struct something {
  char *(*choices[2]);
};

char* arr[2] = {"foo", "bar"};

int main(void) {
  struct something obj;
  *obj.choices = &arr;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably some kind of weird compiler bug. This code compiles fine:

```c
struct something {
  char *** choices;
};

char * arr[2] = {"foo", "bar"};

int main(void) {
  struct something obj;
  obj.choices = &arr;
  return 0;
}
```

And I'm afraid that it's the only workaround that is the most compatible with original idea.

Comment: `obj.choices` has the type of `char ***`, while `&arr` has the type of `char*(*)[2]`. Assignment is from incompatible pointer type. You can change `char ***choices` to `char **choices` and `obj.choices = &arr` into` obj.choices = arr` and compile without any warnings.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks this works, however would you mind explaining how this works ? my (very limited) knowledge of pointers telle me that choices is a pointer to a string, but then how come we can store an array there ? is an array of strings a pointer to a string ?

Comment: The rule is: an array of type is implicitly converted to a pointer to type (except some corner cases, ex. `sizeof`) see [C11 6.3.2.1p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.2.1p3). So an array of `char*` is converted into a pointer to `char*`, so to a `char**`. A "string" in C language, is just z zero byte terminated `char` array. There is nothing special in `char*`. You don't store an array, `&arr` is a pointer to an array of 2 pointers to `char`, ie. `char*(*)[2]`. `arr` has the type of an array of 2 pointers to `char`, but is implicitly converted to a pointer to a pointer to `char`.